# Storm Kafka Topolgy terminates without output

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

This is the StBolt.java class.

```
package com.storm.cassandra;

import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.topology.IBasicBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;


public class StBolt implements IBasicBolt {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(StBolt.class);

private static Session session = null;
private Cluster cluster = null;
String cassandraURL;
JSONObject eventJson = null;
String topicname = null;
String ip = null;
String menu = null;
String product = null;

Row row = null;

com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet viewcount = null;
com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet segmentlistResult = null;
com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet newCountUpdatedResult = null;


public StBolt(String topicname) {
    this.topicname = topicname;
}

public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext topologyContext) {


    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
    System.out.println("load cassandra ip");
    session = cluster.connect();
    System.out.println("CassandraCounterBolt prepare method ended");

}

public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

    System.out.println("Execute");
    Fields fields = input.getFields();

    try {
        eventJson = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON((String) input
                .getValueByField(fields.get(0)));
        topicname = (String) eventJson.get("topicName");
        ip = (String) eventJson.get("ip");
        menu = (String) eventJson.get("menu");
        product = (String) eventJson.get("product");

        String ievent = "ievent";
        String install = "install";

        viewcount = session
                .execute("update webapp.viewcount set count=count+1 where topicname='"+topicname+ 
                        "'and ip= '"+ip+"'and menu='"+menu+"'and product='"+product+"'" );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {

}

public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    return null;
}

public void cleanup() {

}

}
```

Here is the StTopology.java class

```
 package com.storm.cassandra;

 import org.apache.storm.kafka.BrokerHosts;
 import org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;
 import org.apache.storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
 import org.apache.storm.kafka.StringScheme;
 import org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
 import org.apache.storm.Config;
 import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
 import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
 import org.apache.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme;
 import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;


  public class StTopology {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length == 4) {

        BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
        //System.out
        //.println("Insufficent Arguements - topologyName kafkaTopic ZKRoot ID");

        SpoutConfig kafkaConf1 = new SpoutConfig(hosts, args[1], args[2],
                args[3]);
        //System.out
        //.println("Insufficent Arguements - topologyName kafkaTopic ZKRoot ID");

        //kafkaConf1.forceFromStart = false;
        kafkaConf1.zkRoot = args[2];
        kafkaConf1.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout1 = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConf1);

        StBolt countbolt = new StBolt(args[1]);
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("kafkaspout", kafkaSpout1, 1);
        builder.setBolt("counterbolt", countbolt, 1).shuffleGrouping(
                "kafkaspout");
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setDebug(true);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TRIDENT_BATCH_EMIT_INTERVAL_MILLIS, 1);
        config.setNumWorkers(1);
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology(args[0], config, builder.createTopology());

        // StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config,
        // builder.createTopology());

    } else {
        System.out
                .println("Insufficent Arguements - topologyName kafkaTopic ZKRoot ID");
    }
}
 }
```

I am trying to get JSON data from the Kafka console producer, process it in Storm and store it into Cassandra.

For some reason, there is no response from the bolt when I run the code with parameters `viewcount usercount /kafkastorm webapp1`.

I have Kafka getting data from the console producer as topic `usercount`, and the correct table in Cassandra.

The code compiles and runs without any error but the console shows terminated.

I have no activity anywhere, despite providing the right JSON input to the Kafka console producer multiple times `{"topicname":"usercount","ip":"127.0.0.1","menu":"dress","product":"tshirt"}`.

There is no topology shown as being created in the Storm UI's Topology Summary either.

I believe I have all the Kafka, Storm and Cassandra dependencies in place.

Please point me in the right direction with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please place some sleep after submitTopology and see it helps. Normal pattern for LocalCluster is submit topology -> sleep some or do other things -> kill topology -> shutdown cluster.